# Reducing to Irreducible Representations

Tags: matrix, group-theory

## Group Theory Background / Utilities

Suppose I give you a list `G` of matrices which represent some group, in that the matrices are closed under multiplication.  In other words, I provide a list `G` of matrices which have

```
GroupRepresentationQ[matrixRepresentation_]:=And@@Flatten@Outer[
    MemberQ[matrixRepresentation,FullSimplify[#1 . #2]]&,
    matrixRepresentation,
    matrixRepresentation,
    1]
```

and `GroupRepresentationQ[G]==True`.  We can compute the multiplication table via

```
MultiplicationTable[matrixRepresentation_]:=Outer[Position[matrixRepresentation,#][[1,1]]&@*Dot,matrixRepresentation,matrixRepresentation,1]
```

We can compute the conjugacy classes

```
GroupConjugateUnitary[X_][A_]:=FullSimplify[X . A . X\[ConjugateTranspose]]

(* NB: memoized for speed *)
ConjugacyClasses[matrixRepresentation_]:=ConjugacyClasses[matrixRepresentation]=With[
    {conjugations = Flatten/@Table[
        Position[matrixRepresentation,GroupConjugateUnitary[matrixRepresentation[[n]]][g]],
        {g,matrixRepresentation},
        {n,Range[Length[matrixRepresentation]]}
        ]
    },
    Part[matrixRepresentation,#]&/@Union[Union/@conjugations]
]
```

According to (for example) Dresselhaus, Dresselhaus, and Jorio, you can tell if a representation is irreducible by using

```
NIrreps=Length@*ConjugacyClasses;
IrrepQ[matrixRepresentation_]:=(Length[matrixRepresentation]==Total[Map[Length[#] Tr[#[[1]]]^2&,ConjugacyClasses[matrixRepresentation]]])
```

If the set `G` is `Not@*IrrepQ` then there exists a unitary transformation that exposes the fact all of the matrices in `G` may be simultaneously block-diagonalized.  In other words, using

```
blockSplit[reducible_]:=Module[{
    zeroQ=Map[EqualTo[0],reducible,{3}],
    cols,rows,runs
},
    cols=Max/@(Map[Map[Last[Position[#,False]][[1]]&,#]&,zeroQ]\[Transpose]);
    rows=Max/@(Map[Map[Last[Position[#,False]][[1]]&,#\[Transpose]]&,zeroQ]\[Transpose]);
    If[cols!=rows,Print["Problem with blocking!"];Return[0]];
    runs=Partition[{0}~Join~Union[cols],2,1];
    Map[reducible[[All,#[[1]]+1;;#[[2]],#[[1]]+1;;#[[2]]]]&,runs]
]
```

to 'pull apart' the direct sum, there exists a `U` such that `IrrepQ/@blockSplit[GroupConjugateUnitary[U]/@G]` is a vector of `True`s.

## Question

*Q: How can I find a/the unitary transformation `U` that maximally block-diagonalizes all of the matrices in `G`?*

(By maximally, I mean the `IrrepQ/@` statement.)

Note: I'm not going to tell you which group the matrices in `G` represent.  If  you can discover it somehow, great.  But I found that `MultiplicationTable[G]` didn't match any I could find in Mathematica's built-in group theory knowledge (presumably because the matrices are not in the same order as the group elements), and the characters seem not to help because `G` might be extremely reducible.

For example, take the set of twelve 12x12 matrices

```
G = {{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
   0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   1, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}}
```

which (using some manual insight that is not sustainable for all the cases in which I'm interested) comprises irreducible representations only of size 1 and 2.

## First Attempt

Let's not try to do "the whole thing" at once.  In other words, it's enough to find a procedure that can block diagonalize the given reducible representation into two (or more) representations (reducible or irreducible).

I tried the following method

```
blockDiagonalize[reducible_, first_ : False] := Module[{
    c = ConjugacyClasses[reducible],
    m, eig, U, diagonalized
    },
    m = FullSimplify@
    If[first, Total[reducible], c[[1, 1]] + Total@RandomChoice[c[[2 ;;]]]];
    (* The above seems to often work, but it can get stuck, see below! *)
    eig = FullSimplify@Eigensystem[m];
    U = Join @@ Values[
        GroupBy[eig\[Transpose], First, 
        FullSimplify@*Orthogonalize@*Last@*Transpose]];
    diagonalized = GroupConjugateUnitary[U] /@ reducible;
    Return[{U, FullSimplify /@ diagonalized}]]
```

and then

```
{U, d} = blockDiagonalize[G, True];
Map[MatrixPlot, d]
```

shows that `G` is now block diagonal.

[image: a list of MatrixPlots showing a block-diagonal structure]

You can get lists of the blocks using `blockSplit`,

```
b=FullSimplify[blockSplit[d]];
```

and the procedure yielded a set of 1x1 matrices and a set of 11x11 matrices (in this case):

```
b = {{{{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}},
{{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}}, {... a set of matrices that put me over the length limit...}}
```

but `IrrepQ/@b` is `{True, False}`.  Repeating this procedure on those where it is `False` often succeeds, but for the example `G` above it does not (it seems to get stuck on some reducible 4x4 matrices).  Once I repeat the procedure enough to get all all `IrrepQ`s, then I can use the `U`s returned by `blockDiagonalize` to build up the complete unitary transformation.

The "right" answer might be a more direct method or a method that leverages a better knowledge of group theory than I have leveraged :-P, especially in the `blockDiagonalize` method.  It (presumably?) would not rely on `RandomChoice` and would always eventually get all the blocks to be `IrrepQ`.

Comment: A package that helps accomplish this task is provided by Bischer, Döring, and Trautner, in the supplementary material for "Simultaneous block diagonalization of matrices of finite order" 2021 J. Phys. A: Math. Theor. 54 085203 https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/abd979